# Dispense loop in a python pandas dataframe to improve the performance

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got two dataframes dfA and dfB. In dfA there are different events, each with a StartDate ('YYYYmmddHHMM') and an EndDate. In dfB there are temperature values (Temp) for different measuring stations (SID). Each value has also a timestamp ('YYYYmmddHHMM').

The script should calculate the mean temperature for every event in dfA within the StartDate and EndDate and add the number of measuring stations which have a mean temperature between 0°C and -5°C to A.

The following example works fine, but with large dataframes it is very slow. That's why I would like to get rid of the loop.

```
import pandas as pd
dfA = pd.DataFrame({'StartDate':[201601010200, 201601050600, 201602151900, 201812012000],'EndDate':[201601010400, 201601051000, 201602152000, 201812020300]})
dfB = pd.DataFrame({'SID':[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],'Timestamp':[201601010100, 201601010200, 201601010300, 201601010400, 201601010500, 201601010100, 201601010200, 201601010100, 201601010200, 201601010300, 201601010400, 201601010500], 'Temp':[1.2, -1.6, -2.3, 2.0, -5.0, 1.3, 2.6, 8.1, 9.3, -10.5, -20.4, 3.1]})

A = 0

for row in dfA.itertuples():
    cStartDate = row.StartDate
    cEndDate = row.EndDate

    dfC = dfB[(dfB.Timestamp >= cStartDate) & (dfB.Timestamp <= cEndDate)].groupby('SID').mean()
    A += dfC[(dfC.Temp <= 0) & (dfC.Temp >= -5)].shape[0]

print('A: ' + str(A))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a case for cross merge and query. However, for some reason, query is not working with the sample data. Here's a solution:

```
new_df = (dfA.assign(dummy=1)
    .merge(dfB.assign(dummy=1), on='dummy')
)

(new_df[new_df.Timestamp.between(new_df.StartDate, new_df.EndDate)]   # filter the time between each StartDate and EndDate
   .groupby('SID').Temp.mean()                                        # calculate mean of temperature for each SID
   .between(-5,0)                                                     # filter those between -5 and 0
   .sum()
)
# outputs 1
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Unfortunately, it's not working with the real data. The original dfA has 506704 rows and the dfB has 13106173 rows.